# Exception when forwarding request to servlet in Java web application

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, guice, tomcat8

I have a problem and I don't know how to solve it.

My web application `MyApp` is a Maven web application project (Java 8 and Java EE 5). To run an updated version as test instance on the same server, I changed the Context Path of the application from `MyApp` to `MyAppTest`. As servlet container, I'm using Tomcat 8.

The `MyApp` instance is working as expected. However the `MyAppTest` instance is throwing an exception when forwarding the request to one of my servlets. Even if `MyApp` and `MyAppTest` are identical except the context path, this exception occurs. The Servlets are mapped via Guice's ServletModule.

Message:

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -4

StackTrace:

> java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
>   com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition$2.getPathInfo(ServletDefinition.java:212)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:376)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
>   myapp.base.MainEntryServlet.service(MainEntryServlet.java:49)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>   com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doServiceImpl(ServletDefinition.java:286)
>   com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:276)
>   com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline$1.doServiceImpl(ManagedServletPipeline.java:154)
>   com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline$1.forward(ManagedServletPipeline.java:140)
>   myapp.auth.LogoutServlet.service(LogoutServlet.java:57)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>   com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doServiceImpl(ServletDefinition.java:286)
>   com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:276)
>   com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:181)
>   com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:91)
>   com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:85)
>   com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:120)
>   com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:135)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
>   org.apache.coyote.ajp.AbstractAjpProcessor.process(AbstractAjpProcessor.java:873)
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

The Servlet forwarding the Request does this:

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
if (!response.isCommitted()) {
  dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
```

The URL `index.jsp` is mapped to another Servlet. It forwards the request to a JSP:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/theme/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

There the exception occurs. Some other JSPs are included into the `index.jsp` like this:

```
<jsp:include flush="true" page="menu.jsp"/>
```

The `menu.jsp` is located in the same folder as the `index.jsp`.

As mentioned before, everything works fine as long as the Context path is `MyApp`. When changed to `MyAppTest` the exception occurs. It must have something to do with the Context path itself. When changing the Path to `MyAppTest`, the exception message is "String index out of range: -4". When I change the Path to `MyAppTesting`, the exception message changes to "String index out of range: -7".

To solve this I tried the following:

- Changing the Context path and the docBase to `MyAppTest` in the `context.xml` of the project.
- Changing the Artifact ID of the project to `MyAppTest`.
- Changing the Project Name to `MyAppTest`.

Nothing worked. And I don't know what causes the exeption: Maven, Tomcat or Guice.